# How to configure an e-mail address with external MX Record in HostEurope webhosting?

Tags: shared-hosting, mx

I am using the [HostEurope WebHosting Premium](https://www.hosteurope.de/en/Web-Hosting/) package and try to set up e-mail addresses for an [external Domain](https://www.hosteurope.de/faq/domains/verwaltung/externe-domain-webhosting-verwenden/); that is, the domain is not part of the hosting package but externally DNS hosted, and uses a MX Record to point to the HostEurope mailserver.

When trying to create an e-mail address in the HostEurope Customer Information System ("KIS") control panel, it tells me:

> You have set an external MX record for these domains. The configurations made here have no effect on the receipt of e-mails.

The original message when using the German locale was:

> Für diese Domains haben Sie einen externen MX-Record gesetzt. Die hier getätigten Konfigurationen haben keine Auswirkung auf den E-Mail-Empfang.

However, my MX Record points to the HostEurope mail cluster `mx0.webpack.hosteurope.de` as it should. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is due to a quirk in the HostEurope control panel ("KIS"). It happens when you create the domain's MX Record *after* registering the domain as an external domain in the HostEurope control panel. In that case, the control panel will note at the time of registering the domain there that the domain does not use HostEurope's e-mail cluster. And then … it will *never* re-check and update that result on its own, not even after the domain's DNS TTL time has expired.

The simplest way to avoid this is to choose the order of steps wisely:

1. Create the MX Record for the domain, pointing it to `mx0.webpack.hosteurope.de`.
2. Add the domain as an external domain in the KIS under "Domains → External Domains".
3. Create e-mail addresses for the newly registered external domain.

If you already did run into the error condition, you can delete the external domain – and then set it up again, as described above.

Alternatively, go to "Domains → Domain Assignment and Management" and remove the tickmark in column "Ext. MX" for the domain in question. This manually forces the system to re-check if the domain now uses a MX Record that points to the HostEurope mail cluster rather than a non-HostEurope ("external") mail server. This procedure is even contained in the Host Europe FAQ but in a hidden spot and only in German, namely under "[Wie kann ich eine externe Domain bei meinem Webhosting-Paket verwenden?](https://www.hosteurope.de/faq/domains/verwaltung/externe-domain-webhosting-verwenden/)" in section "Externe Domains konnektieren → Hinweis bei Nutzung des Host Europe Mailservers für externe Domains".